# Powershell invoke webrequest issues

Tags: powershell

Purpose of this is to build a simple script to login to a website, put an item in the shopping cart, checkout. Assuming this task can be done with powershell. Not getting an error here but not seeing login information after running. Also, can someone point me to a tutorial on how to add item and to a shopping cart or pointers how to.

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://somewhere.com/login" -SessionVariable sv
$form = $response.Forms[0]
$form.Fields["hdrEmail"] = "myemail@somewhere.com"
$form.Fields["hdrPassword"] = "12345"
$response2 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://somewhere.com/login" -WebSession $sv -Method POST -Body $form
```

I've tried several variations of above using json conversion with no luck. I don't know what to check next. It seem this should be working.

$response2.forms[0].fields shows empty values for the hdrEmail and hdrPassword.
$response.form[0].fields does show hdrEmail and hdrPassword as variable names.